# calculating the top k accuracy using logits vs softmax probabilites

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic, accuracy, softmax

I am working on calculating the top k accuracy of a model my model output logits (I am working on pythorch) so in order to calculate the top k accuracy using sklearn i was wondering what would be the difeerence if I calculate the top k accuracy using the logits vs the softmax probabilites ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The accuracies will be the same. Softmax is a monotonic increasing function, so the argmax on the logit scale is the same as the argmax on the probability scale. Likewise, the top $k$ entries will be the same.

Comment: top_k_accuracy_score(y_true, y_score, k=2)  this is the top k accuracy of sklearn but what I find in their example y_score never some up to 1 ? what y_score could be ? a softmax ?   
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.top_k_accuracy_score.html

Comment: It sounds like you have another question, but the new question is about software. Software questions are not on-topic here, as described in the [help].